# How to data-bind the 'class' or 'id' attribute of a div, while using containerless control flow?

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying out the great new containerless control flow (new feature number 2) at [Knockout 2.0.0 released](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/12/21/knockout-2-0-0-released)   or  http://jsfiddle.net/StevenSanderson/8vms5/light

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>Here is a static header item</strong></li>
    <!-- ko foreach: products -->
    <li>
        <em data-bind="text: name"></em>
        <!-- ko if: manufacturer -->        
           &mdash; made by <span data-bind="text: manufacturer.company"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

What if i wanted something like < li **class="${ name }"**>< /li>

This was trivial while using templates, but i cannot make it work right now.
i tried    < li **data-bind='class: name'**>< /li>    but in vain.

I'm new here, please go easy on me.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use the `css` [binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html).  It can be used two ways. Either with a dynamic class (or list of classes):

```
<li data-bind="css: name"></li>
```

or with individual classes bound against truthy/falsy values to indicate whether that are should be added/removed from the element:

```
<li data-bind="css: { classOne: hasClassOne, classTwo: hasClassTwo }"></li>
```

Comment: If you are using the knockout unobtrusive binding plugin you should write your binding like this: 

`yourElement.dataBind({ attr: { "'class'": 'name'} });`

Comment: "Old versions of IE can complain if class is not in quotes." IE11 complains!

Answer (score 21):

As of mid-2012, there is now the ["css"](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) binding to bind directly to class name.

e.g.:

```
<li data-bind="css: className">**content**</li>
```

Comment: This is way more useful than `attr`, you can have regular classes and an "extra" one that's dynamic, e.g. `<div class="myclass myclass2" data-bind="css: extraClass">`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if someone is wondering how to use "css" attribute with id attribute, i was using both "css" and id attributes, for me it did't work if "css" attribute is not the first one , so keep "css" attribute as your fist one.

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse" data-bind="css:{in:$index()==0}, attr: { id:'collapse'+$index()} ">

...
...
...

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data-bind="attr:{ id:isConditionTrue()<=0 ?'test1':'test2'}"
```

Comment: Please consider describing what is your code snippet doing and format it accordingly.